# Can HListElim be composed with another function?

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, hlist

Given

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.HList
import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.Prelude.List

type family HListElim (ts :: [*]) (a :: *) :: * where
    HListElim '[] a = a
    HListElim (t ': ts) a = t -> HListElim ts a

hListUncurry :: HListElim ts a -> HList ts -> a
hListUncurry f HNil = f
hListUncurry f (HCons x xs) = hListUncurry (f x) xs

hListCurryExpl :: Sing ts -> (HList ts -> a) -> HListElim ts a
hListCurryExpl SNil f = f HNil
hListCurryExpl (SCons _ r) f = \x -> hListCurryExpl r (f . HCons x)

hListCurry :: SingI ts => (HList ts -> a) -> HListElim ts a
hListCurry = hListCurryExpl sing
```

(adapted from https://gist.github.com/timjb/516f04808f0c4aa90c26 and [reroute](https://github.com/agrafix/reroute/blob/master/src/Data/HVect.hs))

I'd like to be able to write a function like the following

```
hListCompose :: (a -> b) -> HListElim as a -> HListElim as b
```

My first attempt was

```
hListCompose f g = hListCurry (fmap f (hListUncurry g))
```

But GHC is telling me that

```
Could not deduce (HListElim ts0 b ~ HListElim ts b)
from the context (HasRep ts)
  bound by the inferred type for ‘hListCompose’:
             HasRep ts => (a -> b) -> HListElim ts a -> HListElim ts b
  at src/Webcrank/Wai/T.hs:64:1-55
NB: ‘HListElim’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘ts0’ is ambiguous
Expected type: (a -> b) -> HListElim ts a -> HListElim ts b
  Actual type: (a -> b) -> HListElim ts0 a -> HListElim ts0 b
When checking that ‘hListCompose’
  has the inferred type ‘forall (ts :: [*]) a b.
                         SingI ts =>
                         (a -> b) -> HListElim ts a -> HListElim ts b’
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: The uncurry was not taken from the github repo you link. It is also equal to curry, so it looks wrong (?).

Comment: @chi Yes, sorry. I was pulling from two different sources and they named things differently and I didn't copy/paste correctly. Updated.

Comment: This looks pretty much the same as [generalized function composition](http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2014-10-17-generalizing-function-composition.html). The trouble that leads that implementation to overlapping instances is presumably going to bite you too: the uncurried version works in a closed kind (nice), and the version with explicit `Compose` works with a specific type (nice), but trying to deal with "looks like a function" vs. "doesn't look like a function" is a bit yucky.

Comment: @Cactus Adding a `Rep as` as an argument would be fine. I'm also interested seeing the `Data.Singletons` approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GHC is right in this case: the basic problem is that because type families need not be injective, `HListElim as a` doesn't specify what the `as` are. (To see why, consider that `HListElim '[] (a -> b) ~ HListElim '[a] b`).

You can get around this if you are willing to add an extra `Sing`leton argument to `hListCompose` to give the `HList` explicitly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
hListCompose :: forall a b as. Sing as -> (a -> b) -> HListElim as a -> HListElim as b
hListCompose s f = go s
  where
    go :: forall ts. Sing ts -> HListElim ts a -> HListElim ts b
    go SNil = f
    go (SCons _ ts) = \g x -> go ts (g x)
```